# Very simple jQuery spoiler functionality half works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented a *really* simple jQuery spoiler functionality using the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" onclick="return false" class="spoiler" content="spoiled content">
    Reveal spoiler
</a>
```

**jQuery / Javascript:**

```
$('a.spoiler').click(function(){
    $text = "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"return false\" class=\"spoiler\" content=\"" + $(this).text() + "\">" + $(this).attr("content") + "</a>"; 
    $(this).replaceWith($text);
});
```

Basically, I just want the spoiler's content attribute to swap with the text in between the tags. It works for the first click, however it does not swap back when clicked again.

Is there any way for me to implement this in a way where it will indefinitely swap the content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
$('a.spoiler').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text(); 
    var content = $(this).attr("content");
    $(this).text(content).attr("content", text)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9qjo80z2/)

Otherwise, You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach as you are using `replaceWith` which is remove elemnent with which event was binded.

```
$(document).on('click','a.spoiler',function(){
    $text = "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"return false\" class=\"spoiler\" content=\"" + $(this).text() + "\">" + $(this).attr("content") + "</a>"; 
    $(this).replaceWith($text);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8cfpk05/)

Comment: Thankyou! That worked! Also a whole lot easier than typing out that string concatenation!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
$('a.spoiler').click(function () {
    $(this).text(function (_, t) {
        return t.trim() == "Reveal spoiler" ? $(this).attr('content') : "Reveal spoiler";
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gLvorqex/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to-

```
$(document).on('click','a.spoiler',function(){
    $text = "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"return false\" class=\"spoiler\" content=\"" + $(this).text() + "\">" + $(this).attr("content") + "</a>"; 
    $(this).replaceWith($text);
});
```

If new HTML is being injected into the page,use **delegated events** to attach an event handler

**Edit**-

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/tfx0s33e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.spoiler').click(function(){
    $text =  $(this).attr("content")
    $(this).attr("content",$(this).text()).text($text);
});
```